# where should I validate data on javaee?

Tags: web-services, validation, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb

I did a search on the board and there were some threads related to what I will ask but the other questions were not exactly like my situation.

I want to implement a service (ejbs) and different clients (rest api, webservice, jsf managed beans and maybe some other client) are going to use this service. My question is: in this scenario, where should data validation occur?

Seems reasonable to me to do it inside my business control (ejbs),- since I don't want to implement one validator type for each client- but I don't see people doing it...

best regards,
Oliver

Comment: I think doing it in one place to void having to replicate code and have it all over your system is a better approach. So in your business control as you stated is a good one. Just throw exceptions for the clients to catch when things don't go right.

Answer (score 0):

The general advice would be: Every component, which exposes functionality to the outside should validate the input it receives. It should not hope for the best that it will in all cases receive valid input. Additionally, as you said, it keeps the validation at one place.

On the other hand it may be a reasonable decision when you have both sides under your control to decide for an early validation on the client and document the expected/required valid input data.
You have a similar problem when designing a relational database structure - you can have all sorts of constraints to ensure valid input data or you can check validity in the component storing the data in the database.
And, not to forget, whenever you validate in a deeper layer, all higher layers have to handle the exceptions or error messages when validation fails.

Regarding your specific question, the usage of the same service from different clients advises  to validate within the service.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Visiting the javaee7 tutorial I found a good solution to my problem: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/bean-validation001.htm#GIRCZ

I think it is the most democratic way to do it BUT it is still good to place client-side validators in order to avoid repeated calls to the server.